# Importing one git repo as a branch into another git repo

Tags: git

For historic reason we have source code for different version in different git repositories. So while Project A holds the version X of the source Project B holds version Y of the source.

Do you guys know a way to import Project B as a branch of Project A?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "git project"?

Comment: sry, i meant a git repository

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is simple with Git. You have to add project B as remote, then fetch:

```
git remote add projectB git://url.to/projectB.git
git fetch projectB
```

Answer (score 32):

I am not sure, what you mean by "git project". In git the states of source code are described by *commits* (a.k.a. revisions). These are stored in repositories, but are independent of the them and can be copied between repositories freely. In fact, to work on the sources git always copies the commits to your local repository that lives in the `.git` directory of your working copy. Branches are just names pointing to commits.

So if you have some branches in one repository and other branches in another repository, you can:

1. Pull both into your local working repository:

   ```
   git remote add B git://url.to/project.B.git
   git fetch B
   ```
2. Base your work on branches from B

   ```
   git checkout -b newname remotes/B/branchname
   ```
3. Push the branches you got from one central repository to the other:

   ```
   git push origin remotes/B/branchname:branchname
   ```

   or the other way around

   ```
   git push B remotes/origin/master:othername
   ```

You can omit the `remotes/` prefix most of the time.

Answer (score 6):

1. First clone project A from git hub

> git clone {git hub Project A URL}

2. Add remote repository  path   of project B

> git remote add projectBrepo {git hub project B URL}

3. project B branches will be fetched

> git fetch projectBrepo

4. check the all branches from project A and project B

> git branch -v -a

5. check-out each branch name from project B (ex:master,  branch_name1)

> git checkout -b  master_old   remotes/projectBrepo/master

6. Push the master branch from project B to project A as master_old

> git push origin master_old

7. check-out branch_name1 from project B

> git checkout -b  branch_name1   remotes/projectBrepo/branch_name1

8. Push the brnach_name1 from project B to project A

> git push  origin   branch_name1