# How to consolidate git forks into git branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fork

I do have to find a way to transform lots of git forks of repositories into git branches inside the same root repository.

In my case people never used real branches, they just forked the repository and did the work on their fork, pushing an pulling from the source repository from time to time but always working on master branch.

I want to consolidate these forks into real branches, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want these forks to become local branches, or would you be content with having remote branches reflecting the work your team members did using the forks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing one git repo as a branch into another git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767381/importing-one-git-repo-as-a-branch-into-another-git-repo)

Comment: I need to keep the history, so their work history (changes made on their fork) are supposed to be visible after the consolidation as changes made on a new branch. So I expect to see branches like: master, imported-fork1, imported-fork2, ....

Comment: Look at the duplicate reference.  You basically can import the branches from the cloned repository into the repo where you want everything to be.

Comment: I think the duplicate reference is missing the last bit of the pussel, how to "merge" the imported fork with this repo. It may be solved by `git branch imported-fork1 fork1/master` (you may need to change the name of the remote ref to match the name you gave the other fork when you added it). You can now push the imported branch to your remote repo as with any other branch.